# Am I able to use an external RFID reader USB-C

Tags: nativescript, rfid

does someone have experience with external devices or especially with Rfid readers? I ordered an external one and still couldn't test because I cannot connect it to my tablet (I would need an USB-A to USB-C converter) but it is necessary for me to know if it's possible or not. If it is not I won't waste my time and send the external reader back.

The reader has a Java development kit (It could theoretically be used in Nativescript but I don't know if NS works with external devices) and there are also some example applications but not based on NativeScript.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript is nothing but a **JavaScript Runtime**, in a nutshell it allows you to write the same Java or Kotlin / Objective C code in JavaScript.

So if your RFID Reader supports a Java Interface, then it's very much possible to read from Android device so NativeScript too.